# meteor + phantomjs FAILS for collection fields more than 10k

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

I have somehow made meteor js work with phantomjs. but PDF is generated only for collection with less 10,000 fields in mongoDB. when I cross the limit to more than 10,000, a blank page is retrieved on browser else things goes as expected.

I used code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114361/generate-pdf-report-in-meteor-js/37139165#37139165)

below is the snapshot of **"top" command** in ubuntu which specifies the memory usage when I generate PDF for more than 10,000 records.

[image]

Also attaching PC configuration below

[image]

Is this memory issue that PDF is not fetched. is there any Meteor/phantomJS memory settings that needs to be enhanced. Please Help!

Comment: CPU has hit 100% which is why things aren't responding

Comment: I can understand that very well from snapshot. But my original question is "is there any Meteor/phantomJS memory settings that needs to be enhanced?", so that such things won't happen? why documents count more than 10K are not working with phantom JS

Comment: no there isn't such a setting